# Plot data according to rownames with different symbols and values

Tags: r, plot

```
a=c(1,2,3,10,30)
b=c(2.5,5,5.5,7,24)
c=c(0,0,5,0,32)

abc=cbind(a,b,c)
rownames(abc)=c("apple","orange","pears","watermelon","mango")
```

Goals:

I would like to plot these data into a same plot, with: data (a) as a line, data (b) as dots symbol, and data (c) as rectangles symbol, with the rownames as x-asix.

Problem I have:

- plotting everything into same plot with different features
- plot according to the fruits' names
- there's one value in each data set
  that is very large (outlier), which makes the plot very wide and dots
  are small.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use classic graphics, use `matplot` (another classic graphics alternativen is provided after the graph) and specify line (`l`), points (`p`) and points (`p`) for the type and the indicated characters (NA == none, 20 is a dot, 15 is a rectangle) and omit the X axis to allow the following `axis` statement to specify the row names.  Finally add a legend.  No packages are used.  [continued after plot]

```
matplot(abc, type = c("l", "p", "p"), pch = c(NA, 20, 15), xaxt = "n")
axis(1, 1:nrow(abc), rownames(abc))
legend("topleft", colnames(abc), lty = c(1, 0, 0), pch = c(NA, 20, 15), col = 1:3)
```

[image: screenshot]

This would also work and would give the same plot.

```
plot(abc[, "a"], xlab = "", ylab = "abc", type = "l", xaxt = "n", 
  ylim = c(0, max(abc)))
points(abc[, "b"], pch = 20, col = 2)
points(abc[, "c"], pch = 15, col = 3)
axis(1, 1:nrow(abc), rownames(abc))
legend("topleft", colnames(abc), lty = c(1, 0, 0), pch = c(NA, 20, 15), col = 1:3)
```

Comment: This works perfectly! However, my actual data has actually >100 rows, so everything clumps together; any suggestion?
* a is the amount of fruits imported, b is the amount of fruits American consume, and c is the amount of fruits Asian consume. I'm trying to compare b and c, while setting a as the avg,

Comment: If you are referring to the fruits at the tick marks then in the `axis` command `las=2` will rotate them and `cex.axis=0.5` will display them at half size.

Comment: I think the main problem is that there're relatively large value (i.e, about 90% of my data are below 100, and 10% are above 2000). So all the small values are packed together on the bottom (super unclear) and a few are on the top of the graph.

Comment: Addomg `log = "y"` to the `matplot` call will plot it on a semilog scale.

Answer (score 0):

An option would  be `matplot`

```
matplot(t(abc), type = 'l')
legend("top", row.names(abc), col = seq_len(nrow(abc)), fill = seq_len(nrow(abc)))
```

[image: plot]